# Why do I have and error bad file descriptor after I close my file descriptor and want to echo some text?

Tags: bash

I wanted to redirect text in if condition. I open two file descriptors and I close them. Everything is working, and the result was redirected to the file. But when I want to echo some text after if condition, it throws an error: bad file descriptor. What's wrong?

```
echo "Enter the number between 5 and 10"
read number

if  [[ $number -le 5 || $number -ge 10 ]]

 then
    
echo "There is an error!"
    
#open file descriptor

    exec 2>error.txt
    echo "---------------------" >&2
    echo "Your answer is $number" >&2
    echo "I wanted you to enter number between 5 and 10!" >&2
    exec 2>&-
else
    
echo "You are really good!"

    #open file descriptor

    exec 1>output.txt
    echo "---------------------"
    echo "You are so cool! Your answer is correct!"
    echo "Your answer was $number"
    exec 1>&-
fi

echo "Some text"
```

Comment: `1>&-` and `2>&-` close stdout and stderr, respectively. What else did you expect to happen?

Comment: In the last line, `echo "Some text"` attempts to print to stdout but you've already closed it by `exec 1>&-`.

Comment: there is no need to change stdout of current shell at all, just redirect the echo line by line (or use a function instead of echo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1` is the file descriptor for standard output. Any command like `echo` write to standard output by "default". A `>` redirection without a number before the `>`, like `>&3` is redirecting standard output of a command, redirecting first file descriptor. Ie. `echo >&3` is exactly equal to `echo 1>&3`.

After you close standard output with `exec 1>&-` then the next command that writes to standard output like `echo "Some text"` will error - because standard output is closed.

So for custom file descriptors use numbers greater or equal to `3` - so not to interfere with standard output `1` or standard error `2`.

But... just group the statements:

```
{
   echo "---------------------"
   echo "Your answer is $number"
   echo "I wanted you to enter number between 5 and 10!" 
} > error.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

before redirecting a standard stream, you can make a copy of it

```sh
exec 3>&1    # fd 3 is now a copy of fd 1

# change fd 1
exec 1>output.txt
echo some text goes to the output file

# restore fd 1
exec 1>&3 3>&-
echo some text goes to stdout
```